# How to use an idris package installed with a nixpkg in another nixpkg?

Tags: idris, nixos, nixpkgs

Currently I am having some trouble using an Idris package that was installed with nixpkg in another Idris package that depends on it. Both of these packages have been tested on a Debian system, so the problem is not with the Idris code itself, but rather somewhere in how they are being installed on the NixOS system. I believe I can successfully install the first package by calling `nix-env -f math.nix -i idris_math` where `math.nix` is defined as:

```
with import <nixpkgs> { };

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "idris_math";
  idris = haskellPackages.idris;
  buildDepends = [ idris ];
  src = ./.;

  preHook = ''
    ln -sv ${idris}/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.0.1/${idris.name}/libs $PWD/libs
    export IDRIS_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/libs
  '';

  configurePhase = ''
    export TARGET=$out/lib/${idris.name}
  '';

  buildPhase = ''
      ${idris}/bin/idris --build *.ipkg
  '';

  installPhase = ''
    ${idris}/bin/idris --install *.ipkg
    ${idris}/bin/idris --clean *.ipkg
  '';

  }
```

I can then run `nix-env -q` and see that `idris_math` has been installed. The second nixpkg looks identical to `math.nix`, except the name is changed and the `buildDepends` line is now `buildDepends = [ idris idris_math ]`. When I try to build or install this package however, I am met with `error: undefined variable 'idris_math'`. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or of a way to fix this?

Comment: You'll have to make Nix aware of what `idris_math` is and this is not achieved by installing it. One way would be using `packageOverride` as explained here: https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-modify-via-packageOverrides

Answer (score 0):

When you write `with import <nixpkgs> {}`, every attribute defined in the Nixpkgs set is essentially made into a local variable. This means that, when you write `haskellPackages`, for example, you are actually referring to the `haskellPackages` attribute defined by Nixpkgs. You can see all the packages defined this way by looking at the file `top-level/all-packages.nix` in your Nixpkgs checkout.

Notice that the `idris` in your `buildDepends` is referring to the definition of an `idris` attribute on the previous line. Your new `idris_math` package isn't similarly defined in this file, or added to the Nixpkgs set anywhere, so you can't get a reference to it by looking for a local variable or for `(import <nixpkgs> {}).idris_math`, which is basically what is being attempted when you write `idris_math` in your second derivation.

Depending on what exactly you want to do with your package, you have a couple of options.  If you just want to use `idris_math` as a dependency for another nearby package (or a few), you can just write `buildDepends = [ idris  (import /path/to/math.nix) ]`. This is a very simple way to do what you want, and very likely a good choice if you want to use this is a library when developing Idris packages.

If you want to make `idris_math` part of the set that you get from `import <nixpkgs> {}` anywhere on your machine, and to make it easy to `nix-env -i`, you can try adding it to an overlay. This would require creating a file like `~/.config/nixpkgs/overlays/<my overlay name>/default.nix` with contents something like:

```
self: super:

with super;

{
  idris_math = callPackage /path/to/idris_math.nix {};
}
```

In this scenario, you probably also want to change your `idris_math.nix` header to be `{ stdenv, haskellPackages }:`, because `callPackage` looks for this kind of definition and it is useful when tying the knot to combine all the overlays together.